# Cannot build VSTO Template projects using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-sdk

We have an existing VSTO Template project, build a long time ago.

Which does not build/compile on my VS2019 machine.

The project does not work on my machine. So I decided the try and rebuild the template project on my machine.

The project raises two errors around an implimentation of a VisualStudio SDK Wizard.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.templatewizard.iwizard?view=visualstudiosdk-2017

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using EnvDTE;
using System.Text;

namespace Corp.ExcelReports.ReportTemplate.WizardExtension
{
    public class ExcelProjectWizard : IWizard
    {
        private WizardForm inputForm;

        #region IWizard Members

        public void RunFinished()
        {
        }

        public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
        {
         }
}
```

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'WizardRunKind' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IWizard' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've found two copies of Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard.dll; dot peek suggests that neither of these DLLs contain a definition for IWizard

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard.dll"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\SQL\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard.dll"
```

What have I missed ?

Answer (score 2):

The [Create a custom template wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-wizards-with-project-templates?view=vs-2019#create-a-custom-template-wizard) section states the following for references:

> Add the following references to the VSIX project. (In Solution Explorer, under the VSIX project node, select References, right-click, and select Add Reference.) In the Add Reference dialog, in the Framework tab, find the System.Windows Forms assembly and select it. Also find and select the System and System.Drawing assemblies. Now select the Extensions tab. Find the EnvDTE assembly and select it. Also find the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizardInterface assembly and select it. Click OK.

On the `Extensions` tab of the `Add References` dialog you can find the required assembly.

[image]